# Directional derivative of $f$ at a point where $f$ is not differentiable

Tags: vector-analysis

Is it possible for the directional derivative to exist for every unit vector $\widehat{u}$ at some point $(a, b)$, but $f$ is not differentiable there.

Please help me to solve.

Comment: see   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390373/difference-between-g%C3%A2teaux-and-fr%C3%AAchet-derivatives/2390428#2390428

Comment: You will surely searching for [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4654785/977780).